# Sum and count of records

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a table with some records:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Row1 | 99 | 152 |
| 1 | Row2 | 99 | 20 |
| 5 | Row3 | 98 | 34 |
| 1 | Row4 | 120 | 18 |
| 7 | Row5 | 27 | 74 |

I need to get the sum of `Col4` values where `Col1 = 1`, sum of `Col4` values where `Col3 = 99` and `Col1 = 1`, sum of `Col4` values where `Col3 <> 99` and `Col1 = 1`, total count of records where `Col1 = 1`, count of records where `Col3 = 99` and `Col1 = 1`, count of records where `Col3 <> 99` and `Col1 = 1` (there is a possibility that there will be no records that meet the criteria).

My SQLite statement looks like that:

```
    query.SQL.Text:= 'SELECT IFNULL(sum(Col4), 0), '+
                     'IFNULL(sum(case when Col3 = 99 then Col4 else 0 end), 0), ' +
                     'IFNULL(sum(case when Col3 <> 99 then Col4 else 0 end), 0), ' +
                     'IFNULL(count(*), 0), ' +
                     'IFNULL(sum(case Col3 = 99 then 1 else 0 end), 0), ' +
                     'IFNULL(sum(case Col3 <> 99 then 1 else 0 end), 0) ' +
                     'FROM myTable WHERE Col1 = :_Col1';
```

Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: *sum of Col4 values where Col1 = 1* I don't see this sum in your code. Also, are there nulls in the columns?

Comment: @forpas `where Col1 = 1` is `FROM myTable WHERE Col1 = :_Col1`. Should not be nulls. Parameter: `query.ParamByName('_Col1').Value := 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite evaluates boolean expressions to `1` (`true`) or `0` (`false`), so a `CASE` expression like:

```
case when Col3 = 99 then 1 else 0 end
```

can be simplified to:

```
Col3 = 99
```

Also, the `ELSE` part in a `CASE` expression like:

```
CASE WHEN Col3 = 99 THEN Col4 ELSE 0 END
```

is not needed because later you use `IFNULL()` to return 0 in case it returns `NULL`.

Finally, `COUNT(*)` never returns `NULL`, so `IFNULL()` is not needed in this case.

Simplify your code to this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Col4), 0),
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Col3 = 99 THEN Col4 END), 0),
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Col3 <> 99 THEN Col4 END), 0),
       COUNT(*),
       IFNULL(SUM(Col3 = 99), 0),
       IFNULL(SUM(Col3 <> 99), 0)
FROM myTable 
WHERE Col1 = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9e6d0eaf8dc450f1927b025bd22b6d8b).

Comment: @bw_üezi yes they are needed in case there are no rows in the table with Col1 = 1.

Comment: if there are no rows with `Col1=1`, then all of the sums will be NULL and the `COUNT` with be 0. The caller can check the count first before accessing the sums

Comment: @RemyLebeau obviously the OP wants to see 0 instead of nulls, this is why IFNULL() is used.

Comment: Yes, i need to see 0 instead of `NULL`.